# Programming on php

Tags: php, variables, command

I would like to execute the following command in php:

```
$output = 'ocr2any.exe -ocr C:\wamp\www\ma-fourniture\commandes\'.$Var.' C:\wamp\www\ma-fourniture\commandes\tst.xls';

$resul = shell_exec($output);
```

I don't know how to to write the variable:  $Var in the command to be executed correctly. The one here does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape backslashes with another backslash:

```
$output = 'ocr2any.exe -ocr C:\\wamp\\www\\ma-fourniture\\commandes\\' . $Var . ' C:\\wamp\\www\\ma-fourniture\\commandes\\tst.xls';

$result = shell_exec($output);
```